# Mysql query showing empty result on vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have an vb.net application which use the mysql for database.

I am facing a problem which is the result of query is always empty.

Below are my codes.

```
Protected Sub btnCheck_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheck.Click

    Dim con As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("prcConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim Sql As New MySqlConnection(con)
    Dim reader2 As Object

    Sql.Open()
    Dim theQuery2 As String = "Select max(shipmentdate) from prc.tbsrparts t where Substring(partsn, 17, 11) =' " & tbPartSN.Text.Substring(16, 11) & "' "  'get latest shipment date from database

    Dim command2 As New MySqlCommand(theQuery2, Sql)

    reader2 = command2.ExecuteScalar
    lbl90days.Text = reader2.ToString


End Sub
```

The result should be shown at label lbl90days.

But mine is always empty.

Can anyone guide me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried your query in mysql?

Comment: yes..it works on mysql.

Comment: I'm bit confused here, why you need compared `Substring(partsn, 17, 11)` with a `space` and `tbPartSN.Text.Substring(16, 11)`? Why not just compared `Substring(partsn, 16, 11)` and `tbPartSN.Text.Substring(16, 11)` or maybe  `Substring(partsn, 17, 11)` and `tbPartSN.Text.Substring(17, 11)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to solve by

```
Dim PartSN As String = tbPartSN.Text.Substring(16, 11)
```

And replace theQuery2 code with

```
Dim theQuery2 As String = "SELECT Max(shipmentdate) FROM prc.tbsrparts t WHERE Substring(partsn, 17, 11) = '" + PartSN.ToString + "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Protected Sub btnCheck_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheck.Click
    Dim con As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("prcConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim Sql As New MySqlConnection(con)
    Dim reader2 As Object

    Sql.Open()
    Dim theQuery2 As String = "Select max(shipmentdate) from prc.tbsrparts t where Substring(partsn, 16, 11) = @PartSN"

    Dim command2 As New MySqlCommand(theQuery2, Sql)
    command2.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartSN", tbPartSN.Text.Substring(16, 11))        

    reader2 = command2.ExecuteScalar
    lbl90days.Text = reader2.ToString
    Sql.close()
End Sub
```